# HttpClient with Mutual TLS and DelegatingHandler for logging request/response throws exception

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I want to log the request and response of a `HttpClient` with a `LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler`, but I get the error `A task was canceled`. The `HttpClient` connects over TLS.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(MutualTlsHandler());

private WebRequestHandler MutualTlsHandler()
{
    var certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection { ClientConfiguration.Certificate };
    var mutualTlsHandler = new WebRequestHandler();

    mutualTlsHandler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificateCollection);
    mutualTlsHandler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = IsValidServerCertificate;

    return mutualTlsHandler;
}
```

This works like a charm, but I want to log the request being sent. Trying to create a `LoggingHandler` and add it to the chain results in the error `A task was canceled`.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(MutualTlsHandler())

internal class LoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public LoggingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    } 
}
```

I would presume that reading using `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` results in a stream that needs to be rewinded, but how can this be accomplished? Copying using `Content.CopyToAsync` results in the same error.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `HttpClientFactory` in this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/.

With that added I think you can do:

```
HttpClientFactory.Create(mutualTlsHandler, loggingHandler);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives the same result. It is confusing that it is possible to have multiple `DelegatingHandler`s in a chain reading the content, but as soon as a `WebRequestHandler` is introduced, it fails.